# Why is it the halocho (law) that persuading others to give is greater than giving?

Tags: halacha-theory, tzedakah-charity, mussar-ethics

Chazal say, "Gadol hame’aseh yosair min ha’oseh," "the one causing others to give tzedakah is greater than the person giving the tzedakah" ([Bava Basra 9a](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=23&daf=9&format=pdf)).

The [Shulchan Oruch YD 249 (5)](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9732&st=&pgnum=412&hilite=) brings this down as Halocho “If a person can persuade other people to give, his reward is greater than that of the giver”.

Why is this codified as halocho (law) – it sounds more like mussar (ethical teaching)?